# ¿Cómo refactorizar este código de JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un proyecto donde en alguna que otra página utilizo más de un datatable de jQuery para mostrar la información. Sin embargo, el código el 90% es el mismo para todos los datatables exceptuando el campo "Buscar", que tiene un id distinto para cada uno para que no busquen todos igual.

Entonces, se me ocurre que podría reducir el código si se pudiera hacer un datatable base y llamar ese código pasándo el parámetro para el id del "Buscar".

Para que os hagáis una idea, actualmente tengo esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tabla1 = $('#tabla1').DataTable($.extend( true, {}, {
    }, Parametros);
    $("div.buscar1").html('<label>Buscar:</label><input class="search form-control m-input--solid" id="buscar1" style="height: 43px;" placeholder="Texto a buscar..." />');
    $('#buscar1').on('keyup', function () {
        tabla1.search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
    tabla1.columns().iterator('column', function (ctx, idx) {
        $(tabla1.column(idx).header() ).append('<span class="sort-icon"/>');
    });

    var tabla2 = $('#tabla2').DataTable($.extend( true, {}, {
    }, Parametros);
    $("div.buscar2").html('<label>Buscar:</label><input class="search form-control m-input--solid" id="buscar2" style="height: 43px;" placeholder="Texto a buscar..." />');
    $('#buscar2').on('keyup', function () {
        tabla2.search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
    tabla2.columns().iterator('column', function (ctx, idx) {
        $(tabla2.column(idx).header() ).append('<span class="sort-icon"/>');
    });
});
```

Comment: qué has intentado? conoces MVC?

Comment: Por supuesto, es un proyecto de Laravel y ahora mismo estoy refactorizando código. He reducido bastante lo que había pero ahora estoy atascado aquí. De hecho, había intentado crear un fichero .js, poner el datatable allí y luego pasarle parámetros, pero no sé si sería factible dado que esto es en el DOM, si llamo a un fichero JS quizá pierda el foco...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lo primero de todo, no dupliques código, cuando en una zona de código copies y pegues, sabes que eso va a otro método.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function search(div, id, tabla) {
        $(div).html(`<label>Buscar:</label><input class="search form-control m-input--solid" id="${id}" style="height: 43px;" placeholder="Texto a buscar..." />`);
        $(id).on('keyup', function () {
            tabla.search($(this).val()).draw();
        });
        tabla.columns().iterator('column', function (ctx, idx) {
            $(tabla.column(idx).header() ).append('<span class="sort-icon"/>');
        });
    }

    var tabla1 = $('#tabla1').DataTable($.extend( true, {}, {
    }, Parametros);
    search("div.buscar1", '#buscar1', tabla1);

    var tabla2 = $('#tabla2').DataTable($.extend( true, {}, {
    }, Parametros);
    search("div.buscar2", '#buscar2', tabla2);
});
```

No ahorra muchas lineas si solo tienes 2, pero el código es más limpio.

El nombre de los parámetros del método cambialos por los que tu veas conveniente.

Un saludo.

Comment: Podrías meter `let tabla = $(tablaId).DataTable($.extend( true, {}, {
    }, Parametros);` dentro de la función, recibiendo el ID de la tabla como parámetro en lugar de la tabla ya generada

Comment: @angogi, he probado tu código y el evento 'keyup' no lo tiene en cuenta, con lo que, la parte del buscar queda inutilizada...

Comment: Ya está, fallo mio. Ha funcionado perfecto angogi, muchas gracias!